# Como definir a propriedade HREF do HTML dinamicamente, com alpine.js?

Tags: javascript

Tenho uma tabela Datatable sendo alimentada por AlpineJS:

```
<template x-for="user in users" :key="user.Id">
```

No x-for, tenho o valor de user.Id que consigo listar em um campo SPAN, com a instrução x-text:

```
<span id="user.Id" class="text-gray-700 px-6 py-3 flex items-center" x-text="user.Id"></span>
```

Preciso concatenar o valor de user.Id no final da minha propriedade HREF, qua vai chamar uma rota no backend para inativação de um registro:

De forma direta, tentando definir a propriedade HREF + user.Id, não deu certo, então pensei no seguinte:

```
<script>                                    
   var uid = document.getElementById("user.Id");
   console.log('Valor de uid: ' + uid.InnerText);
   var link = document.getElementById("link");
   link.setAttribute('href', 'http://api-paulinhomonteiro-com.umbler.net/cli/delete/<%= token %>/' + uid.innertText)
</script>
```

Funcionou muito bem setando a propriedade dinamicamente mas a variável chega como undefined.

Como eu poderia resolver isso? Acabei de descobrir AlpineJS e não consigo avançar.

P.S. Prezados, apesar da grande ajuda do amigo #LeAndrade, ainda não consegui resolver. O ponto é: como utilizar o conteúdo da variável x-text, concatenado com o HREF?

Comment: Nesse `log` o valor de **uid.InnerText** vem como o que?

Comment: Olá LeAndrade, obrigado por responder. O valor chega como UNDEFINED.

Comment: Sim pq colocou **InnerText** com o i em maiúsculo.

Comment: Caro LeAndrade... TENS TODA A RAZÃO. O que faz a falta de atenção... Muitíssimo obrigado pela resposta. Problema resolvido aqui! Grande abraço e obrigado.

Comment: Por nada amigo, sucesso aí!

Comment: Prezados, apesar da grande ajuda do amigo #LeAndrade, ainda não consegui resolver. O ponto é: como utilizar o conteúdo da variável x-text, concatenado com o HREF?

Comment: A todos que ajudaram de alguma maneira, em especial a @LeAndrare, meu muito obrigado! Solução encontrada aqui: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902261/problem-to-concatenate-alpinejs-x-text-and-href-property/61913267#61913267](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61902261/problem-to-concatenate-alpinejs-x-text-and-href-property/61913267#61913267) Se alguém precisar de alguma ajuda com AlpineJS ou Tailwind, já estou com uma pequena bagagem e recomendo demais as ferramentas. Grande abraço!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Creio que o autor já encontrou a resposta como [ele mesmo comentou](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/452643/como-definir-a-propriedade-href-do-html-dinamicamente-com-javascript/490463#comment865334_452643), ainda sim para formular a resposta visando ajudar futuros visitantes. Antes de responder, para quem tiver dúvidas de onde encontrar a documentação do [alpine.js](/questions/tagged/alpine.js), ela se encontra diretamente no github deles e também está disponível em português:

- https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/blob/master/README.pt.md#aprenda

O `x-bind` é que permite que um atributo em um elemento receba o valor de uma expressão JavaScript, ficando algo como:

```
<a x-bind:href="'foo/bar/delete/<%=token%>' + user.Id">Apagar</a>
```

No entanto vale lembrar que a sintaxe `x-bind:atributo=` tem um atalho sendo apenas `:atributo=` e isso que poderia ser feito apenas assim:

```
<a :href="'foo/bar/delete/<%=token%>' + user.Id">Apagar</a>
```

Exemplo (passe o mouse sobre o link e veja que o "ID" muda a cada segundo:

```js
function myData()
{
    return {
        user: null,
        fetchData() {
            let randomID = 0;
            setInterval(() => {
                this.user = { "id": ++randomID };
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/alpinejs/alpine@v2/dist/alpine.min.js" defer></script>

<div x-data="myData()" x-init="fetchData()">
    <template x-if="user">
        <a :href="`#foobar=${user.id}`">link com :href</a><br>
        <a :href="`#foobar=${user.id}`">link com x-bind:href</a>
    </template>
</div>
```

Outros "recursos" para usar com os elementos do seu template:

| Directiva | Descrição |
| --- | --- |
| `x-data` | Declara um novo escopo do componente |
| `x-init` | Executa uma expressão quando um componente é inicializado |
| `x-show` | Alterna `display: none;` no elemento dependendo da expressão (true ou false) |
| `x-bind` | Define o valor de um atributo para o resultado de uma expressão JS |
| `x-on` | Anexa um evento de escuta ao elemento. Executa a expressão JS quando emitida |
| `x-model` | Adiciona "ligação de dados bidirecional" a um elemento. Mantém o elemento de entrada sincronizado com os dados do componente |
| `x-text` | Funciona da mesma forma que o `x-bind`, mas atualiza o `innerText` de um elemento |
| `x-html` | Funciona de maneira semelhante ao `x-bind`, mas atualiza o `innerHTML` de um elemento |
| `x-ref` | Maneira conveniente de recuperar elementos DOM fora do seu componente |
| `x-if` | Remove um elemento completamente na DOM. Precisa de usar uma tag `<template>` |
| `x-for` | Crie novos nós DOM para cada item em uma matriz. Precisa de usar uma tag `<template>` |
| `x-transition` | Diretrizes para aplicar classes a vários estágios da transição de um elemento |
| `x-spread` | Permite definir um objeto de diretivas Alpine, a um elemento para melhor reutilização |
| `x-cloak` | Este atributo é removido quando o Alpine é inicializado. Útil para ocultar a pré-inicialização da DOM |